# How to access file uploaded in one solution to another solution in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have two solution one is user solution and second is admin solution. i run or debug both the solution . In user side user upload document or file and saved file in server. when admin login from admin solution he get name of list of file uploaded by user and after clicked on file name  he get error that 'The resource cannot be found' same as user also get list of file as reply from admin and he also get error 'The resource cannot be found.' Below path stored in web conifg file in admin solution

```
<add key="adminpath" value="http://localhost:54321/"/>
<add key="userpath" value="http://localhost:61866/"/>
```

In user solution Below path stored in web conifg

```
<add key="adminpath" value="http://localhost:54321/"/>
<add key="userpath" value="http://localhost:61866/"/>
```

thanks 
manohar

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~") + "/yourfolder/"
```

I think you can't download a file in 2 differrent link

yourlocalhost:54321/files/somefile.zip is different with yourlocalhost:61866/files/somefile.zip

So, Map path with server can solve it.